# PropertyError Discord.js v14

Tags: compiler-errors, discord.js

I'm using Discord.js version 14, there is a problem with integrations, I know the `.addField` no longer exists, now it's `.addFields`. I looked carefully at the documentation but the command shows that there is an error. For information, I am French, the order will be English!

Error:

> Uncaught _CombinedPropertyError Error: Received one or more errors

The command:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client({ 
    intents: [
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
]
    });


client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("bot opérationnel");
});

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
 
    //+help
 if (message.content === prefix + "help"){
    const embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor("#ffcc00")
        .setTitle("**__Les commandes du bot ATHENA:__**")
        .setURL("https://discord.js.org/")
        .setDescription("Vous trouverez toutes les commmandes dont vous pouvez faire usage")
        .addFields("**__+help__**", "Affiche la liste des commandes")
        .addFields("**__Support Developpement__**", "https://discord.gg/H9mSXeAm8C");
            
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]});
```

So I would like to have an answer to this because it bothers me a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Are you missing ```});```?  or did you not include it by mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the field parameters in the wrong format. The `addFields` function takes one or more field objects as parameters. See [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/builders/1.7.0/EmbedBuilder:Class#addFields).

Keeping this in mind your code could look something like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ 
    intents: [
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
    ]
});

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("bot opérationnel");
});

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
 
    // +help
    if (message.content === prefix + "help") {
        const embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor('#ffcc00')
            .setTitle('**__Les commandes du bot ATHENA:__**')
            .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
            .setDescription('Vous trouverez toutes les commmandes dont vous pouvez faire usage')
            .addFields(
                { name: '**__+help__**', value: 'Affiche la liste des commandes' },
                { name: '**__Support Developpement__**', value: 'https://discord.gg/H9mSXeAm8C' }
            );
            
        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
});
```